# How do I save a wordpress theme's files and install them on another site?

Tags: theme-development, themes, migration

I have two sites I run with Wordpress. I put a lot of work into making a custom theme for site #1 so it looks and functions well and I want to download all of the theme's files (php/js/css, etc. no content) and install them on site #2. Site #1 and Site #2 have different content and I don't want the content touched. How would I go about doing this?

I looked in my file manager on my hosting and the html/css/js stuff is in a few different folders (wp-admin, wp-content, and wp-includes, and the themes folder is inside the wp-content coverage which is confusing to me), so I don't know exactly how I'd copy and install it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If your theme was developed correctly all of your assets should be stored in:

```
/wp-content/themes/theme-name/
```

Simply copy your theme folder and drop it into the same location on a new site. From there you can activate it via Appearence -> Themes in your WordPress backend.

If you have any plugins you need to copy over you can do the exact same thing with plugin folders too. You'll find those at this location:

```
/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/
```